# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: linker command warning

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I updated my pods, and then after closing the project and reopening it, I received this error that I've been trying to figure out for 5 hours, and nothing has worked for me. I've been told to change the architectures, but all that I've tried isn't working, and I'm struggling a lot. Here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Vloggle' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use 
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'KILabel'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'ColorSlider'
pod 'lottie-ios'

# Pods for Vloggle

target 'VloggleTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'VloggleUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
```

end

Also, here is a screenshot of my build settings.

[image: Build Settings]

Here is the error message
[image]

Comment: Did you clean / build?

Comment: Yes multiple times

Comment: Any reason why you haven't posted relevant, useful parts of the error message in your question?

Comment: I'll add the screenshot now

Comment: @rmaddy i just added a screenshot of the error message i am getting

Answer (score 0):

Latest iOS version supports 64bit of Architecture. So you have to use Valid Architectures. You can check this in the "Architecture" section in build settings.

You can see the "Architecture" setting in the screenshot which is as follows:-

If your architecture is correct then check the "Other Linker Flags".

You can change the "Other Linker Flags" in the **"Build Settings"**.
Search "Other Linker Flag" in the search area in the "Build Settings" and add the following code in it

$(inheriterd) will add all type of linker flags generated by the pods while installation of pods

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgHV6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xouyo.png

Comment: I changed my valid architectures to be the same as in the screenshot, and my linker flags are the same too. I am still gettin the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please check the following steps in your project:-

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the following settings in your project:-

1) Select your project target
2) Go to Build Phases
3) Go to Link Binary With Libraries
4) Press + to link

Make sure all libraries under Workspace have been added. If any library is missing then please add the missing library. Please check the attached screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NghA7.png